# Convexity of a function of generalized inverse CDF.

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-distributions, convex-analysis, quantile

How can I prove (or disprove) that the following function is convex on $X$.
$$\rho(X,Z) =  Max \{ F^{-1}_Z(t)-F^{-1}_X(t),0 \},$$ 
where $F^{-1}_X(t)= inf \{ x : F_X(x) \geq t \}$ with $0 \le t \le 1$. Here
$F_X(x)=P(X \le x)$, is the CDF of $X$.

If it is convex then we need to prove: $\rho( \lambda X + (1-\lambda)Y,Z) \le \lambda\rho(X,Z) + (1-\lambda) \rho(Y,Z) $.

I dont know how to proceed. It will be helpful if i can get some guidance.

Comment: Is that $\max$ over $t$?

Comment: No. $t$ is just a fixed quantity in $[0,1$].

Comment: Then your question seems to reduce to asking whether $r(x)=\max\{k-x,0\}$ is a convex function of $x$